# Draw a graph from a list of connected nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, coordinates, nodes, edges

In a system I Have a list of nodes which are connected like in a normal graph. We know the whole system and all of their connections and we also have a startpoint. All my edges has a direction.

Now I want to draw all of these nodes and edges automatically. The problem is not the actual drawing, but calculating the (x,y) coordinates. So basically I would like to draw this whole graph so it looks good.

My datastructure would be something like:

```
class node:
string text
List<edge> connections
```

There must be some well known algorithms for this problem? I haven't been able to find any, but I might be using the wrong keywords.

**My thoughts:**

One way would be to position our startnode at (0,0), and then have some constant which is "distance". Then for each neighbor, it would add distance to the y position, and for each node which is a neighbor, set x= distance*n.

But this will really give a lot of problems - so that's definetely not the way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By far the most common approach for this is to use a [force-directed layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29) instead of a deterministic one. The gist is that you have every node repel each other (anti-gravity) and have any connected pairs of nodes attract each other. After several iterations of a physics simulation you can get a reasonable layout.

There are many layout algorithms you can use, with vastly different results. The [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) fdp ([Fruchterman & Reingold '91](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/spe.4380211102)) and neato ([Kamada & Kawai '89](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2889%2990102-6)) algorithms work, but are rather old and there are much better alternatives. The [Fruchterman & Reingold '91](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/spe.4380211102) algorithm is also available in Python in [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout).

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org) provides a [ForceDirectedLayout Java class](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/action/layout/graph/ForceDirectedLayout.html) that is pretty fast and good. [Hachul & Jünger '05](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-31843-9_29) detail the FM^3 algorithm, which appears to do quite well in practice ([Hachul & Jünger '06](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11618058_22)) and is available in C++ in [Tulip](http://tulip.labri.fr).

There are tons of other open source tools to visualize graphs, like
[NodeXL](https://nodexl.codeplex.com/) (C#), a great introductory tool that integrates network analysis into Excel 2007/2010 (*Disclaimer: I'm an advisor for it*). Other awesome tools include [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) (Java) and [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) (Java), while [Pajek](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/), [UCINet](https://sites.google.com/site/ucinetsoftware/home), [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) and [Tom Sawyer](http://www.tomsawyer.com/products/layout/index.php) are some proprietary alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

In general this is a tricky problem, especially if you want to start dealing with edge routing and making things look pretty. You might look at http://www.graphviz.org/ and using either their command line tools, or using the graphviz library to do your layout and get your x,y coordinates within your application.